# searching the perfect data structure for storing and retrieving the elements

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I have to choose one data structure for my need below i am explaining the conditions there are following values

```
abc,def,rty,ytr,dft   which all are map to row R1B1 (actully key is combination of R1+B1)
abEERc,dFFFef,rGGty   which all are map to row R1B2 (actully key is combination of R1+B2)
```

```
  KEY                      VALUE
abc,def,rty,ytr,dft --->    R1B1
abEERc,dFFFef,rGGty --->    R1B2
```

now, for example, let's say, if i get `ytr` then i would be able to retrieve `R1B1`
or, let's say, i get the value `rGGty` then i would be able to retrieve  `R1B2`

now the case is that matters is of search, complexity and the time taken as the things have to go in sequence

for example, it will first pick the first line to search `ytr`, it will first match it with  `abc` which will not match then will have to match with `def` it will not again match then it will match with `rty` which will not also match then it will finally match with `ytr` and finally it will find the key `R1B1` finally

similarly if the second string need to be searched lets say `rGGty` then it would scan first row in which it will not find the value then search would continue to second row and also in second row in the third element it would get `rGGty` as element then it would retrieve `R1B2` as value

let's say, if put this thing in map then a sequence search will go on key and then only we will be able to find the corresponding value

Folks please advise which will be the best data structure i can implement in java in which i will have to search the keys items to find the corresponding value in very fast time also which will not hit the performance too
,the kind of data structure performance should be very high

Please advise folks also it would be great if some one can advise me to show how this can be achieved using digital trees

Comment: Why not just use a HashMap?

Comment: A hashtable to map strings to value and a hashtable to store the inverse mapping from values to 'sets' of strings.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks for the suggestion but still not able to grasp request you to please explain in detail if possible a little bit of code can help to understand more

Comment: @saadtaame Thanks for the advise , request you to please explain indetil so that i cn grasp more please Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you asking exactly the same question twice?

Comment: @TagirValeev please go through the whole question series it is liitle bit different please

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest you can simply use a HashMap or HashTable,
 if you insist on implementing a structure on your own i would suggest a search trie.
In a search trie the number of maximum comparisons required to retrieve data is equal to the length of the key used, so to retrieve data for the given keys(abc,def,rty,ytr,dft) exactly 3 comparisons would be required
Consider the following wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie
Also below is my quick and dirty implementation of a search trie (provided the keys are standard ASCII letters) :)-

```
public class DictionaryNode 
{
    DictionaryNode next[];
    String data;
    DictionaryNode()
    {
        next=new DictionaryNode[128];
        for(int i=0;i<next.length;i++)
        {
            next[i]=null;
        }
        data=null;
    }
}

public class Dictionary 
{
    DictionaryNode root;
    Dictionary()
    {
        root = new DictionaryNode();
    }
    public boolean add(String key,String data)
    {
        char[]ch=key.toCharArray();
        DictionaryNode current=root;
        for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
        {
            if(current.next[ch[0]]==null)
            {
                current.next[ch[0]]=new DictionaryNode();
            }
            current=current.next[ch[0]];
        }
        if(current.data==null)
        {
            current.data=data;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public String search(String key)
    {
        char[]ch=key.toCharArray();
        DictionaryNode current=root;
        for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
        {
            if(current.next[ch[0]]==null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                current=current.next[ch[0]];
            }
        }
        return current.data;
    }
}

public class main {
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Dictionary d=new Dictionary();
        d.add("abc", "R1B1");
        d.add("def", "R1B1");
        d.add("rty", "R1B1");
        d.add("ytr", "R1B1");
        d.add("dft", "R1B1");
        System.out.println(d.search("abc"));
        System.out.println(d.search("ab"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , request you to please explain in detail a little bit that how the above piece of code is working that will help to rasp more Thanks

Comment: also please explain that as mentioned In a search trie the number of maximum comparisons required to retrieve data is equal to the length of the key used , so lets say i put  case in which the key length is 6 and one key length is 10 then will it impact performance

Comment: @eretg ghg A search trie is a data structure where each node in the tree can be said to be a character in the key, please have a look at the wikipedia article, that should explain the structure better than i can in a comment, also regarding the point of the key length being 6 or 10 it will indeed impact performance if you have very few keys however consider a key length of 10, we can retrieve any key in 10 comparisons out of 62^10 possible keys!! if you have very few keys than no matter which algorithm you use you will get similar performance eg (linear search or binary search)

Comment: Thanks a lot well the above structure that you have posted works for me but still there will be keys that i am going to put into will be of very length say few keys will be of 4chars length then there will be few keys of 10 chars length so this kind if mix up of length of keys will be there so in that case will it impact that performance Thanks inadvance

Comment: There should not be any impact, (keys of length 4 will take 4 comparisons to retrieve whereas keys of length 10 will take 10 comparisons to retrieve) longer keys will have a minor overhead in terms of memory as more intermediate nodes are required but it should not be a significant restriction unless you have a memory constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Inverse key and values in your case and use Multimap data structure. See good article here about `Multimap`. http://tomjefferys.blogspot.com/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html

```
@Test
public void getColor(){
    Multimap<String,String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();


    myMultimap.put("R1B1","abc");
    myMultimap.put("R1B2","def");

    myMultimap.put("R1B2","abEERc");
    myMultimap.put("R1B2","rGGty");

    Multimap<String, String> invertedMultimap = Multimaps.invertFrom(myMultimap, ArrayListMultimap.<String, String>create());

    System.out.println(invertedMultimap.get("abc"));

}
```

Comment: Thanks can you please advise how can this help me in my above problem statement please , request you to please post the code that will help to grasp me

Comment: can you please explain what is happening in the above program specially with context to invertedMultimap specially what is happening in the section invertFrom